# Having a hard time finding the minimum price in an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
class FindMinTester1 extends Vehiclehw {

    Vehiclehw [] myVehicles = new Vehiclehw[100]; 

    public static double findMin (Vehiclehw[] theVehicles) { 

        int min = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < Vehiclehw.length-1; i++) {
            if(Vehiclehw[i].getprice() < min)
                min = Vehiclehw[i].getprice;
        }
        return Vehiclehw;
    }
}
```

// So I understand the problem is a bit vague but basically I have a super class called Vehiclehw that has a price and in this class Im trying to find the lowest price in the array of 100 elements. I know there are no objects declared but I more or less just need to know how I would go about writing this method given the problem. All I was given was the first two lines. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you start the `min` at zero, will any price be less than it ever?

Comment: `int min = Vehiclehw[0].getprice();`.... `return min;`.

Comment: @CoolMind works great until `theVehicles` is empty, then we have an AIOOBE.

Comment: @ggorlen, agree with you, but I thought it had 100 elements.

Comment: Sure but the spec can change at some arbitrary point in the future, then all the code breaks.

Comment: @ggorlen, yes. While we discussed, somebody copied our solution. :)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, well, what do you mean about that answer?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, I understood. Well, at that moment it was rather a joke, because a solution is quite simple (and we both could write the same code, even if didn't see each other). Sorry.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, thank you! I also saw you profile and found that you became very popular. Glad to hear you!

Answer (score 0):

Do it as follows:

```
class FindMinTester1 extends Vehiclehw {

    Vehiclehw[] myVehicles = new Vehiclehw[100];

    public static double findMin(Vehiclehw[] theVehicles) {
        if (theVehicles.length == 0){
            return (-Double.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        double min = theVehicles[0].getprice();

        for (int i = 1; i < theVehicles.length; i++) {
            if (theVehicles[i].getprice() < min)
                min = theVehicles[i].getprice();
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. Assume you have just one price in the array. In that case, it will also be the minimum price. Therefore, you should always assign the first price to the variable, `min` and then compare it with the next price. If the next price is less than the value of `min`, assign that value to `min`. Repeat it with all prices in the list. Note that because of `i < theVehicles.length - 1`, your loop terminates at one element still left to be compared. It should be `i < theVehicles.length`.
2. Your other mistake was to return the array itself while it was required to return the minimum price (which is stored in `min`).
3. The third thing you must have considered was to declare `min` as `double` instead of `int`.
4. Return some value e.g. the minimum value of `double` to avoid the program crashing for an empty array.
5. You have written `return Vehiclehw` where `Vehiclehw` is the name of the superclass. This is wrong; you should return a value.

Comment: Thats seems to look correct my only issue is that it keeps saying that Vehiclehw cannot be resolved to a variable and also gives me an error on the .length part of the if statement. But I cannot figure out why

Comment: Yes this indeed works for me I appreciate your help so much thank you.